# Javascript - is there any hard limit (or performance impact) for namespace nesting?

Tags: javascript, performance, namespaces, limit

I'm trying to learn a bit more about Javascript apart from the typical `var x = function(){...}` constructs, so I gone for namespaces.

In PHP, I always work with namespaces to avoid collisions and to organize my constants, classes and functions. So far, I've just done the basic namespacing like this:

```
var helpers = {
    strings: {
        add: function(a, b) {
            alert(a + ' plus ' + b + ' equals to ' + (a + b));
        },
        msgbox: function(text) {
            alert(text);
        }
    }
}
```

So I can write HTML blocks like this:

```
<button class="ui-button" type="button" onclick="helpers.strings.msgbox('Hello, world!');"><img src="assets/images/alert.png" alt="Alert">&nbsp;Click me!</button>
```

My questions are:

- is there any practical/hard limit to the number of levels I can nest my namespaces within?
- is there any performance impact associated with the level of nesting for any given function?
- can I extend a given namespace later in time? Like... having a `core.js` file and extending the `strings` namespace for adding more functions in, let's say, `extended.js`?

I'm not going to build a horribly nested structure or anything like that but I would just like to know if there are any practical limitations imposed by the browser engine or the language itself, so my question is more of a theorical nature (I'm not building a construct to test this, in this case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there any practical/hard limit to the number of levels I can nest
>   my namespaces within?

Obviously there is because if nothing else more levels will require more memory and memory is finite, and in practice there other restrictions will also be in place (derived from the implementation details of each particular JavaScript engine).

But the *practical* answer is: if you have reason to believe you might go near these limits, you are doing something wrong.

> is there any performance impact associated with the level of nesting
>   for any given function?

Yes, because each level of indirection involves finding where the next nested "namespace" object is in memory and looking up its properties. In practice this cost is infinitesimal compared to other stuff that your code will be doing, so you will not be able to measure any difference unless the number of levels is large and you are digging up a nested value within a loop.

For example, this is not the best of ideas:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 1000000000; ++i) {
    ns1.ns2.ns3.ns4.ns5.ns6.ns7.ns8.ns9.ns10.ns11.ns12.ns13.count += 1;
}
```

Fortunately if you ever need to do this there is a simple workaround:

```
var ns13 = ns1.ns2.ns3.ns4.ns5.ns6.ns7.ns8.ns9.ns10.ns11.ns12.ns13;
for(var i = 0; i < 1000000000; ++i) {
    ns13.count += 1;
}
```

> can I extend a given namespace later in time? Like... having a core.js
>   file and extending the strings namespace for adding more functions in,
>   let's say, extended.js?

You can, but you have to be careful so that both of these files use a mechanism for injecting variables into a namespace that does not actually *replace* the contents of the namespace.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer :) Like I said in my initial post, I'm not building a horrible nested structure, but something like I currently do for PHP. I have a space for string functions called `Helpers\Strings` and I would like to have a javascript counterpart with the same naming convention as `helpers.strings`.

Out of that use case, my level of nesting won't ever exceed that of the 2nd level, 3rd for an extremely rare case, but that's where I'll draw the line.

Answer (score 1):

There is a slight performance hit for each level of nesting, as it's another lookup.  And there's the additional overhead of downloading more code if this is for client-side scripting.  The first is likely quite minor.  The second you'll have to decide for yourself.

And you can easily add new functions to your namespaces later:

```
helpers.strings.multiply = function(a, b) { /* ... 8/}
```

Although I made heavy use of namespacing for years, I rarely do so now, preferring a module loading system to manage my dependencies, and not exposing even something like `helper`.  But these sorts of namespaces are easy to create and easy to use if you choose to do so.

Comment: That's why I chose the namespacing route. Less collisions and a bit more of organization, plus doing just a couple of levels of nesting won't hurt that much (but I had the concern in mind, anyway) :P